# Cannot restore database with .mdf extension in sql server

Tags: sql-server, localdb, database-restore

I have back-up my database from `LocalDB` server which is `.mdf` file:

`C:\THESIS - SOURCE CODE\SIS-JEN\SIS\APP_DATA\SIS_DB.MDF`

and it was successfully backed-up with an extension of `.bak`:

`C:\THESIS - SOURCE CODE\SIS-JEN\SIS\APP_DATA\SIS_DB.MDF.bak`

Now, I want to restore this back-up file to the new server(my pc/server), but I cannot successfully restore using the `.bak` file:

`C:\THESIS - SOURCE CODE\SIS-JEN\SIS\APP_DATA\SIS_DB.MDF.bak`

I've got this error:

> Restore of database 'C:\THESIS-SOURCE
>   CODE\SIS-JEN\SIS\APP_DATA\SIS.DB.MDF' failed

[image]
Can anybody help me to fix this error?

Comment: If you're restoring via Management Studio, click on the error that appears to see more information about the cause.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check about `RESTORE` statement -

```
USE [master]
GO

RESTORE DATABASE [SIS_DB] FROM DISK = N'D:\SIS_DB.bak'
    WITH FILE = 1,
    MOVE N'SIS_DB' TO N'D:\SIS_DB.mdf',
    MOVE N'SIS_DB_log' TO N'D:\SIS_DB_log.ldf', NOUNLOAD
```

Comment: I need to restore this database to another server not in localdb